# bounded linear functional on $\ell^{1}$, and its relation to $\ell^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, lp-spaces

Prove that a bounded linear functional $F$ on $\ell^1$ has representation
$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(c_{n}x_{n})$ where $c_{n} \in \ell^{\infty}$, and that $\|F\|_{*} = \|c_{n}\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: I think you mean the sequence $(c_n)$ in the last two occurrence of $c_n$.

Comment: @VahidShirbisheh: I think he means so.

Comment: Check that $T:l^\infty\to (l^1)^*$ defined by $T_c(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx_n$ for $c\in l^\infty$ and $x\in l^1$ is a isometric isomorphism so that $l^\infty\cong (l^1)^*$.

Answer (score 2):

Put $c_n = F(e_n)$, then clearly, $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n x_n$. (*Hint*: take $s_n = (x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n, 0, 0, \ldots)$, then $s_n$ converges to $x$ in $l^1$; apply bounded linear property of $F$ here).

Now, because $\|e_n\|_1 \leq 1$ (hence $|c_n|\leq \|F\|_*$) for all $n$, we have $(c_n) \in l^{\infty}$ . This also implies
$$
\|(c_n)\|_{\infty} \leq \|F\|_*.
$$

Finally, Holder's inequality gives us:
$$ |F(x)| \leq \|(c_n)\|_{\infty} \|x\|_1,$$
which implies the reversed inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c_n = F(e_n)$, where $e_n$ is the vector of zeroes except for a one in the $n$th place. Since $\|e_n\|=1$, and $F$ is bounded, we see that $|F(e_n)| =|c_n| \le \|F\|$, and so $\|c\|_\infty \le \|F\|$.

Suppose $x \in l_1$, then $x = \sum_n x_n e_n$, where $\|x\|_1 = \sum_n |x_n| < \infty$. Let $x_N = \sum_{n \le N} x_n e_n$, then it is straightforward to see that $x_N \to x$, and since $F$ is bounded we have  $F(x_N) = \sum_{n \le N} c_n x_n \to F(x)$, and so $F(x) =  \sum_n c_n x_n$, from which we have $\|F(x)\| \le \sum_n |c_n| |x_n| \le \|c\|_\infty \sum_n |x_n| = \|c\|_\infty \|x\|_1$, and so $\|F\| \le \|c\|_\infty$.